# create 2-d vector using objects c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a 2-d vector using objects from class A but I get the following error.

```
 error: no matching function for call 'std::vector<A>::push_back(A*)'
```

I am using the code below to create my vector. I have used a similar code like this to create a 2-d vector of boolean by just changing the 'A' to 'bool' in the code below. I have no idea why this is not working.

not working code

```
std::vector<std::vector<A> > board;
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    board.push_back(vector<A>());  //insert rows
}

for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        board[i].push_back(new A(i,j));  //insert cols and value
    }
}
```

working code

```
vector<vector<bool> > board;
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    board.push_back(vector<bool>());
}

for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        board[i].push_back(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use `new` to create an object of that class? You are trying to push a pointer into a vector of objects.

Comment: are you serious! damn.. my brains just freezed. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
board[i].push_back(new A(i,j)); // new A(..) returns A *
```

should became

```
board[i].push_back(A(i,j)); // A(..) return A
```

Comment: every time I declared an object without an object name I used pointer. So had no clue about this. Thanks

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim A(i,j) is a call to a constructor of class A. It will create and return object of type A: `A a = A(i, j);` same is `A a(i, j);`

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim: _"every time I declared an object without an object name I used pointer"_ Then your code likely has a _ton_ of memory leaks!!

Answer (score 2):

You write:

```
board[i].push_back(new A(i,j));
```

`new A(i,j)` a value of type `A*` (pointer to `A`).  You should instead push a value of type `A` .  Thats what you should write:

```
board[i].push_back(A(i,j));
```

Comment: `board[i].emplace_back(i, j);` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get says everything you need to know

> error: no matching function for call 'std::vector::push_back(A*)'

The compiler cannot find a function call for inserting a pointer to an `A` object into the `std::vector`.

With the line:

```
board[i].push_back(new A(i,j));
```

You are trying to push a pointer to the `std::vector`. 
Either you change your data structure to

```
std::vector<std::vector<A*>> board;
```

(keep in mind to **free** the memory afterwards and also to change the initialization)

or you change your method call to

```
board[i].push_back(A(i,j));
```

Comment: `board[i].emplace_back(i, j);` would be better.